# How to efficiently flatten a NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have a NSOutlineView which is binded to my NSTreeController. The content of the NSTreecontroller (myTreeController) is set with data using the command:
    [self.myTreeController setContent:self.myArrayOfFiles];
The content of the array consists of NSTreeNode parent and children objects that are added using a NSTreeNode subclass (TKnode):

`[TKnode treeNodeWithRepresentedObject:myRootObject]`.

This works very well and displays my NSoutlineView correctly.  But when I want to iterate over the content of the NSOutlineView I need to flatten it and store the objects in an array.  This is where I could need some help as the solution I have is not optimal and potentially prone to errors.

I first return the content of the NSTreeController using:

```
 - (NSArray *)rootNodes;
{
    return [[myTreeController arrangedObjects] childNodes] ;
}
```

This returns a NSTreeControllerTreeNode array of size one that holds the tree structure. I then access the first layer of the tree structure using the childNodes method.

```
- (NSArray *)flattenedNodes
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for (TKnode *rootnode in [self rootNodes]){
        for (TKnode *node in [rootnode childNodes]){

            if (![[node representedObject] isLeaf]){
                [mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[self descendants:[node representedObject]]];
            }
            else {
                [mutableArray addObject:[[node representedObject] representedObject]];
            }
        }
    }
    DLog(@"My files: %lu",[mutableArray count]);
    return [[mutableArray copy] autorelease];
}
```

The children of the children are accessed recursively using the following method:

```
- (NSArray *)descendants:(TKnode *) node
{
    NSMutableArray *descendantsArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for (TKnode *mynode in [node childNodes]) {

        [descendantsArray addObject:[mynode representedObject]];

        if (!mynode.isLeaf){
            [descendantsArray addObjectsFromArray:[self descendants:mynode]];
        }
    }
    return [[descendantsArray copy] autorelease]; // return immutable
}
```

This works and returns an array containing all of my objects, not the NSTreeNodes, but the objects I am interested in. But it seems error prone that I have to call representedObject sometimes twice on an object to access my object. Is this the way I am supposed to work with NSTReeController and NSTreeNodes? Is there a better way? The reason I wanted to use NSTreeNode and NSTreeController in the first place was to get some of the already implemented methods for free such as sorting and arrangedObjects, which I am used to with NSTableView. But the method I use to access the NSTreeController content does not seem correct ? Should I use the `arrangedObjects` to get the content of the NSTReeController or should I use a different approach? Any suggestions for how to correctly flatten a NSOutlineView is highly appreciated.

Thanks! Cheers, Trond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question turned out to be a real tumbleweed (my second in one month) so I wanted to follow up with some more info. I ended up using the above posted code for flattening my NSOutlineView as I was unable to find a better option. When you have to recursively iterate through an unknown number of subfolders (in my case) this seems to be the best option where the `descendants` method is called for each time you reach a deeper level. I found a very useful website with a number of useful NSTreeController extensions [here](https://wabbit.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Wabbitstudio/Mac/WabbitStudio/WabbitCode/NSTreeController+WCExtensions.m), which uses the same approach as I had taken. Unless someone helps me figure out a faster and better algorithm for flattening the arrangedObjects of a NSTreeController, I believe i will stick with this approach.

Cheers, Trond

**Update:** After a question for the solution I decided to post my method for how to flatten an outlineview. I hope his can help others.

```
- (void) flattenOutlineview
{
    NSMutableArray *nodeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.myFlattenedFiles removeAllObjects];
    [self.myFlattenedNodes removeAllObjects];
    [self.myIndexDict removeAllObjects];
    [nodeArray removeAllObjects];

    for (SDNode *rootnode in self.rootNodes)
    {
        [nodeArray addObject:rootnode];

        [self.myIndexDict setObject:[rootnode indexPath]
                             forKey:[[[rootnode representedObject] representedObject] fullpathL]];

        for (SDNode *node in [rootnode childNodes])
        {
            if (node.isLeaf){
                [nodeArray addObject:node];
                 [self.myIndexDict setObject:[node indexPath]
                                 forKey:[[[node representedObject] representedObject] fullPathCopy]];
            }
            else {
                [nodeArray addObjectsFromArray:[self descendants:node]];
                [self descendantsIndex:node];
           }  
       }  
   }
   [self.myFlattenedNodes setArray:[nodeArray copy]];

   for (SDNode *node in self.myFlattenedNodes)
   {
       [self.myFlattenedFiles addObject:[[node representedObject] representedObject]];
   }
}
```

Comment: Can u send the treeController demo code.  Because we stuck with here. We are parsing the directories, need to display in tree view. Example app. 
thanks.

Comment: @user2553442: Please see my updated answer. Hope this helps. T

Comment: Do u have sample code of this NSOutlineView.. @Trond Kristiansen

Comment: What do you mean sample code? I just posted the whole method ? T.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this linked from another answer I just wrote.  Provided you have everything in the tree expanded/displayed this would work:

```
for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < [outlineView numberOfRows]; row++)
{
    NSTreeNode* node = [outlineView itemAtRow:row];
    [nodeArray addObject:node];
}
```

The rows of the outlineView are basically a flattened tree.  And you could perhaps expand every item while iterating to get them all.